# How to see the hourly traffic of a website using Google Analytics (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics

As a site owner, it is important for me to determine the best time of the day to apply patches and updates to the web server and to the code of the website.

I used to see the hourly traffic report in Google Analytics. I believe that this was one of the original reports included since Google Analytics launched.

Could anyone share how to do it?

I was expecting to see an hourly site traffic report. I have clicked everywhere in GA4 and I can't find that report.

I'm guessing that I'm supposed to create a report myself, but it is not obvious to me how to do so.

As an alternative, I could install on my server a package like AWStats, but since it is 2023 I think I should be able to do this with Google Analytics.

All the information I have found online is for older versions of Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

For the GA report You want to go to your GA4 property, go to Explorer, pull the Hour dimension and the Pageview metric. Put them into the table however you like them there. Change the date as you need it.

Usually, 3, 4 and 5 AM are the lowest traffic hours within one timezone.

Keep in mind that GA and other front-end analytics systems are subjects to adblockers and other client-side scripts, so it's always good to have something like AWStats in place as well as proper settings for web-server logging and log rotation. The default settings are not proper. Web-server logs are super useful since they're bulletproof, unlike front-end analytics.